# In Google's directory API, what hash format is required when "crypt" is provided as the hashFunction for a user?

Tags: hash, crypt, google-directory-api

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/update), `hashFunction` accepts 'crypt' as a valid value. My problem is figuring out what type of hash this actually is.

A request with a hash generated by PHPs password_hash function (which I understand uses crypt) fails to work.

The request:

[image: Example request using Google's API explorer]

The response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid Input: $2y$10$qCE0dkXTyFIg6VmqZ/24AuH0Xo5vb8ce3pX9FhRQn5bJzUnAYLax."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid Input: $2y$10$qCE0dkXTyFIg6VmqZ/24AuH0Xo5vb8ce3pX9FhRQn5bJzUnAYLax."
 }
}
```

(The provided hash is generated from the password "hello").

What's an example of a valid hash that Google will accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I've figured it out (example passwords are both `hello`):

- Passwords generated with a [DES-based scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(C)#Traditional_DES-based_scheme) are accepted

  - Example: saPPmoXIbs91M
- Passwords generated with a [MD5-based scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(C)#MD5-based_scheme) (starting with $1$) are accepted

  - Example: $1$2p5.hs1.$.MKLW7B4Bi.EQMd6agPzO.
- Passwords generated with an SHA-256 or SHA-512 based scheme (starting with $5$ and $6$ respectively) are accepted
- Passwords generated with a [Blowfish-based scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(C)#Blowfish-based_scheme) (starting with $2) are **not accepted**

The accepted hashes are the same type of hash that `htpasswd` creates using either `-m` or `-d`.

Passwords generated with `crypt($password)` in PHP will be accepted (if you don't specify a salt), but the newer, more secure `password_hash($password)` will not.

Comment: PHP 5.6 or later raise an `E_NOTICE` if `crypt` is not given a salt.